# Socket io prevent concurrent mysql queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I have 2 users that emits 'create_todo' function at the same time. 'create_todo' has multiple mysql queries that are now overlapping. Is there a way to prevent this async behavior so that createTodo() function would wait untill all queries are finished.

I'm using nodejs with socket.io 2.3.0

**Code Sample**

```
// server

socket.on('create_todo', function(payload) {                                                                                                                           
  createTodo(name, status, titleId, userId);                                                         
});


async function createTodo(name, status, titleId, userId) {

  const db = makeDb();                                                                                   
                                                                                                     
  try {                                                                                                  
    await db.beginTransaction();
    console.log('start transaction userId: ', userId);                                                   
    
    const res = await db.query(                                                                          
      'INSERT INTO todo_items (name, status, todo_title_id, modifier) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',                 
      [name, status, titleId, userId]);
                                                                                                                                                                
    console.log('phase 1 ');                                                                             
    await db.query(                                                                          
      'UPDATE todo_items SET order_number = (SELECT c FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM 
        todo_items WHERE todo_title_id = ? AND id <= ?) t) WHERE todo_items.id = ?',                                                           
      [titleId, res.insertId, res.insertId]);                                                         
                                                                                                   
    console.log('phase 2 ');                                                                             
    const rows = await db.query(                                                                         
      'SELECT todo_items.id, todo_items.name, todo_items.status, todo_items.order_number, 
        users.username FROM todo_items INNER JOIN users ON todo_items.modifier = users.id 
        WHERE todo_title_id = ? AND todo_items.id = ?',                                                       
      [titleId, res.insertId]);                                                                         
                                                                                            
    console.log('phase 3');                                                                              
    await db.commit();                                                                                   
    console.log('commit');                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                               
    todoItems.to('title/' + titleId).emit('create_todo', {                                               
      id: rows[0].id,                                                                                    
      name: rows[0].name,                                                                                
      status: rows[0].status,                                                                            
      modifier: rows[0].username,                                                                        
      orderNumber: rows[0].order_number                                                                  
    });                                                                                                  
  } catch (e) {                                                                                          
    await db.rollback();                                                                                                                          
  } finally {                                                                                            
    await db.close();                                                                                    
    console.log('db close');                                                                             
  }           
}
```

**Current Behavior**

```
start transaction userId:  1
start transaction userId:  2
phase 1 
phase 1 
phase 2 
phase 3
commit
db close
phase 2 
phase 3
commit
db close
```

**Expected Behavior**

```
start transaction userId:  1
phase 1 
phase 2 
phase 3 
commit
db close
start transaction userId:  2 
phase 1
phase 2 
phase 3
commit
db close
```

Also I have tried with promise chaining aswell.

Comment: What issue are you trying to prevent/seeing by blocking the code for running asynchronously? Based on the code you have this is working as it should. The transaction only locks the other rows once it hits query between phase1 and phase2. Blocking the asynchronous nature of what you’ve written would slow your application down so you should avoid it where possible. That said, a whole table lock could do what you wanted, but you’d likely have to implement that yourself using a separate table

Comment: use select for update in the first query. When you  select, it place read lock which other process can still read from it. However if you select for update, it will place a write lock with default isolate , other connection cannot read and have to wait.